# How to set sizes of ASAP7nm transistors in NGSPICE (or HSPICE)

Tags: ngspice, hspice, netlists

I want to write a netlist of a basic two-stage amplifier using the ASAP 7nm predictive technology and simulate it using NGSPICE.
There are some useful instructions and files in [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/678378/is-this-ngspice-simulation-correct-with-asap7-transistor-models).

However, I don't know how to set the sizes for each transistor in my netlist. How can I determine the number of fingers, fins per finger, or W and L?